# Install failure for pytables in terminal

Tags: python-3.x, pytables

When I try 'pip install pytable', it yields the error 'no matching distribution found for basicproperty>=0.6.9a'. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Pytables is referenced in python hosted projects as tables

Use `pip install tables`

For more details check https://www.pytables.org/usersguide/installation.html